# Selenium Press & Hold blocker

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha

I'm facing the captcha kind of issue when I'm using selenium to scrape the data from the site (See the attached screenshot). The thing is even if I manually tried to solve the captcha also, but the site is not allowing me to solve the blocker. What could be the solution I could have done to avoid the captcha?
[Captcha screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9JEz.png)

I've tried undetacted-driver  (https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/) and switching the user-agent. But nothing worked